# How to prove that the system of ODE's won't have any negative solutions?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a system of ODE's:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{S}=-\alpha S(t)I(t),\\
\dot{I}=\alpha S(t)I(t)-\beta I.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I have already drew the graphs for both of the functions. I can see that the functions will never be less than 0, wich is also true because functions represent the number of population.

[image]

I know that the $\dot{S}$ function for $S$ in $t=0$ equals 0, which means that the function is constant.

My question is how do I prove that the solutions to the system of ODE's will never be less than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact negative solutions: if your initial condition has a negative value, it will stay negative (at least for a while).  The correct statement is that if the initial values $S(0)$ and $I(0)$ are positive, the solutions will stay positive for all future time.

One way to see this is that if a solution ever becomes negative, it must pass through $0$.  But the solution with $I(t_0) = 0$, $S(t_0) = s_0$ is constant $I(t) = 0$, $S(t) = s_0$, while the solution with $I(t_0) = i_0$, $S(t_0) = 0$ is $I(t) = i_0 e^{-\beta (t-t_0)}$, $S(t) = 0$.  Thus if $I(t)$ is ever $0$, it must always be $0$, and if $S(t)$ is ever $0$, it must always be $0$
(and have always been $0$).